# fcntl2.h and unistd.h error when I ctrl + leftclick into the open() or read() function(it is into function definition)

Tags: c++, c, ubuntu

- env: I use vscode ssh remote plug-in link ubuntu20.04(it run in orangepi3b, I don't know if that's the problem.)
- question:
  1.1 when I ctrl + mouse leftclick, after clicking `open()` function is not into `usr/include/fcntl.h` function declaration, but into `usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h` function definition.
  1.2 `read()` function also into `usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu/bits/unistd.h` function definition.
  1.3 `open()` and `read()` can show the smart tip.The `truncate()`function does not have a smart tip.

All the code I've written **compiles with gcc and it can run**.
how to solve these question.

- this is my c_cpp_properties.json:

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "includePath": [
                // "/usr/include",
                // "/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "browse": {
                "path": [
                // "/usr/include",
                // "/usr/include/aarch64-linux-gnu",
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ]
            
            // "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true
            },
            "defines": [],
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "cStandard": "c11",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "linux-gcc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

[c_cpp_properties.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQEQE.png)

- using truncate():
  [using truncate()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6A6R.png)
- using read():
  [using read()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9M0nD.png)
- this is the error:
  [open() error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKu7E.png)
  [read() error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJsCw.png)

**my try**:

1. Modify includePath, browse.path, compilerPath, intelliSenseMode in c_cpp_properties.json.
   1.1 includePath and browse.path to add the paths that have been commented out.
   1.2 **intelliSenseMode** change to `"linux-gcc-x64"`, `"linux-gcc-arm64"`, `"linux-gcc-x86"`, `"linux-gcc-arm"`.
   1.3 **compilerPath** to `"aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc"`
2. Reinstalling the system on orangepi3b(ubuntu 20.04)

Comment: [Please do not post images of code because they are hard to use.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) Code should be posted directly **as text** in your question.

Comment: but images can be directly displayed to report errors

Comment: If there is something wrong in your config file, how would you expect anyone to copy and highlight it from a picture?

Comment: sorry, I didn't think of that. I'll change it right away.

Comment: anybody can help me?

Comment: I honestly don't understand what question you're asking. Please be precise! As a new user here, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: ok, I will do it later